# Apache error instead of varnish error

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I configured varnish for my client .Now my client want to see apache error instead of varnish backend fetch failed in browser .Is there any option available varnish 4.

Comment: Perhaps you can return a "synth()" custom made error page from Varnish when your specific error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, there is no option to do so.

You either `pipe` the requests to see everything from backend (bypassing Varnish), or you have default behaviour of `503 Backend fetch failed` on errors from backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VCL to serve the apache error page. By default Varnish, on error, will serve its preconfigured error page.
In vcl_backend_response detect if Apache is erroring, if that's the case, retunr(deliver) to serve the Apache error page.
If you share you VCL I can have a look at it.